# pandas: within groupby functions to select rows with some criteria paris

Tags: python, pandas

Buddys: I have a dataframe like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'code':'A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B', 'B','B','B'), 'Times': (1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6),'Figure':(2.3,4.1,5.2,7.0,1.8,9.0,4.2,7.9,4.6,1.4,9.7,1.2)})
```

so the structure like this:

```
>>> df
    Figure  Times code
0      2.3      1    A
1      4.1      2    A
2      5.2      3    A
3      7.0      4    A
4      1.8      5    A
5      9.0      6    A
6      4.2      1    B
7      7.9      2    B
8      4.6      3    B
9      1.4      4    B
10     9.7      5    B
11     1.2      6    B
```

Now I want to within each code group ('A', 'B'), calculate differences of Figure only when Times pairs in [[4,1],[6,1],[3,2]]. So the desired new dataframe would like this:

```
>>> newdf
  code  diffFigure diffTimes
0    A         4.7       4-1
1    A         6.7       3-2
2    A         1.1       6-1
3    B        -3.3       4-1
4    B        -2.8       3-2
5    B        -3.0       6-1
```

Of course, I would like to use groupby functions and apply a function:

```
def f(x):
    myList = [[4,1],[6,1],[3,2]]
    for i in x.itertuples():
        for j in x.itertuples():
            if (i.Times, j.Times) in myList:
                print (i.code + ": " + str(i.Times) + "-" + str(j.Times) + "=" + str(i.Figure - j.Figure))
newdf = df.groupby('code').apply(f)
```

But I cant get the desired dataframe. Here two problems: Firstly any possible ways not using itertuples to enumerate around all rows? Secondly in the function f, how to design return format to get the desired dataframe?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible solutions:

Either make use of `.unstack()`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'code':('A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B', 'B','B','B'), 'Times': (1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6),'Figure':(2.3,4.1,5.2,7.0,1.8,9.0,4.2,7.9,4.6,1.4,9.7,1.2)})
df = df.set_index(["code","Times"]).unstack()
```

and manually concatenate the differences in a for loop, i.e.:

```
myList = [[4,1],[6,1],[3,2]]
pd.concat(((df[('Figure',d1)] - df[('Figure',d0)]).to_frame('diffFigure').assign(diffTimes="{}-{}".format(d1,d0)) for (d1,d0) in myList))
```

or make a list of all the possible combinations within each code:

```
df0 = df.merge(df, on = 'code')
```

Then take the subset of pairs which is in `myList` by turning `myList` into a dataframe and doing an inner join operation:

```
df0 = df0.merge(pd.DataFrame(myList, columns = ['Times_x','Times_y']))
df0['diffFigure'] = df0.Figure_x - df0.Figure_y
df0['diffTimes'] = df0.Times_x.astype(str) + '-' + df0.Times_y.astype(str)

df0[['code','diffFigure','diffTimes']]
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I preferred the first solutions since the second solution consider all combinations of Times and may has more lapse.

Comment: The relative performance also depends on how many entries you have in `myList`. Calls to pandas functions are generally slow, so if you have to iterate through the for loop many times, it would be faster just to do one big merge, calculation and subset, as long as you can fit the data into memory.